# How can I embed a test data set in my JMeter test plan?

Tags: jmeter

At the moment, my JMeter test uses a `CSV Data Set Config` to iterate through a limited set of input data for each HTTP request that I do.

But I don't want to deal with the hassle of an external file (uploading it to my test runner, etc.) - I'd like to just embed the data into the jmx file itself.

I was hoping for something like a "test data" node, that would work similarly to a CSV data set (with `Recycle on EOF` especially) and I'd just copy/paste the data into the test plan instead of working with an external file.

I'm thinking I might be able to work around it with a JSR223 preprocessor - but is there a better built-in way?

**Edit**: As per comment: the data cannot be generated.

Comment: Do you mean load variable in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables or http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters?

Comment: if data is of form user1, user2 ....., usern or of such kind then counters can help you generate such data but if its complete random then its good to place it in an external file. Your solution of embedding into jmx file is not good in case of large dataset. uploading a small file on testrunner machines is not a big problem and can easily be solved by using a shared storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first go at a script based approach using a JSR223 preprocessor node:

```
// This is where the data is embedded. Up to a couple of hundred entries 
// is probably fine, more than that will likely be a bad idea.
def messageIdList = ["graffle", "wibble", "wobble", "flobble", "gibble", ...]

def messageIndex = (vars.getIteration() -1) % (messageIdList.size() -1)

println "iteration ${vars.iteration}, size ${messageIdList.size()}, index: ${messageIndex}"

vars.put("messageId", messageIdList[messageIndex]);
messageIndex++
```

This appears to do what I want, even when run in a `Thread Group` with multiple threads. 
I'm not sure exactly what the `vars.getIteration()` represents, and I'm not clear about the precise lifetime / scope of the variables. But it'll do for now.

Any better answers will cheerfully accepted, marked and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language correct syntax would be

> vars.**put**("messageId", "wibble");

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for available functions and properties.

---

Easier way would be going for [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) or [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) or even better [Set Variables Action](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-set-variables-action-component-in-jmeter)

Comment: The `User Parameters` link you gave looks about right if I were actually doing 5 as per my answer.  But I've now pasted in a couple hundred and it seems to work fine.  I don't want to do that by hand using JMeter's GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text contains keys and values separated with tab, copy all text

- Notice if you have property file you can replace `=` with tab

Add to JMeter GUI  [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)  and click `Add from Clipboard`

It'll load all your variables to JMeter without "do that by hand using JMeter's GUI"

.